# how to update with select in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql

i have two tables, tableA and tableB, tableA is phone master record and tableB contains the update status of the last transctions within the phone records of tableA. I want to update value tableA.active to b'0'  for all records in tableB.status='ERROR'.

This is the MySQL statement that i came with, but is giving me the error (**Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row**)

```
UPDATE tableA set tableA.active = b'0'
where
tableA.phone =
(Select  phone from  tableB  where tableB.status='ERROR');
```

Comment: Aside: I can't help wondering whether `NULL` would be a more appropriate value for `tableA.active` in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`=` cannot only match one row, as the error said. You can use `IN` instead:

```
UPDATE tableA set tableA.active = b'0'
where
tableA.phone IN
(Select  phone from  tableB  where tableB.status='ERROR');
```

Comment: +1. More information: [§13.2.10.3 "Subqueries with ANY, IN, or SOME" in the MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html).

Comment: As [suggested by @ruakh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114871/how-to-update-with-select-in-mysql/12114924#comment16196644_12114891), one could also use `= ANY` and `= SOME`.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to [@Mathieu Imbert's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12114891/623041), you can use the multiple-table `UPDATE` syntax to join the tables:

```
UPDATE tableA JOIN tableB USING (phone)
SET    tableA.active = b'0' WHERE tableB.status = 'ERROR'
```